# How to solve "IntegrityError at /measurements/ NOT NULL constraint failed: diabetes_measurements.patient_id" probem in django

Tags: django

I have made a form which name is ***MeasurementsForm*** by using ***Measurements*** model. by whenever I use `form.save()` in views, it throws an error and does not  store data. but if i do not use `form.save()` it does not throw an error also does not store data. in Measurements model, I have a field name patient which has foreign key relation with user sign up custom model. now how to fix this and store data after submitting the form.

my models:

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    d_value=models.IntegerField()
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    patient=models.ForeignKey(UserSignupModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient)
```

my forms :

```
class MeasurementsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    d_value=forms.IntegerField(help_text="insert the diabetes")
    class Meta:
        model=Measurements
        fields=('d_value',)
```

my views:

```
def measurement(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
        form=MeasurementsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('home')

    else:
        form=MeasurementsForm()

    return render(request,'diabetes/measurement.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Is `UserSignupModel` the user model (set in the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`)? If not, can you show the model and how it links to the user model?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this fails is because your form never specifies the `patient`, and when you submit it to the database, the database will thus reject this.

You can set the `.patient` of the instance wrapped in the form. If the `UserSignupModel` is for example the user model (you specified with the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-user-model)), then we can set this with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def measurement(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=MeasurementsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.patient = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form=MeasurementsForm()
    return render(request,'diabetes/measurement.html',{'form':form})
```

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: yes! UsersignUp model is the model that i specified in AUTH_USER_MODEL.

Comment: yes! it works ,thanks a lot. can you please tell me what is the purpose of @login_required

Comment: @imtinan: it is in the note at the bottom of the answer (together with a link to the documentation) :)